# OAMutableURLRequest - NSURLErrorDomain error -1012

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm getting this error trying to post a request to hattrick.org using SAOAuthTwitterEngine Oauth authentication.
With all the GET requests everything works fine, but only one call must be in POST with a JSON string and this one doesn't work.

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn't be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.).

I'm sure the request must be in http!
Here the code.

```
NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];    

OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:finalURL
                                                               consumer:self.consumer
                                                                  token:_accessToken
                                                                  realm:nil
                                                      signatureProvider:nil];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:body]];

OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];  
[fetcher fetchDataWithRequest: request delegate: self didFinishSelector:@selector(testApiCallResult:didFinish:) didFailSelector: @selector(testApiCallResult:didFail:)];

return responseBodyToReturn;
```

I don't know how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you occurred in a bug on the library...

Try with another, my suggestion is to use this:

[gdata-objectivec-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/OAuthSignInControllers)